# Reproduzir Som (WINDOWS)

Tags: c, c++

Como eu faço para reproduzir som em um programa desenvolvido na linguagem C/C++? 
**Ambiente (WINDOWS)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função **PlaySound** reproduz um som especificado pelo nome do arquivo fornecido.
da uma olhada nos dados da MSDN para melhores informações -> [PlaySound MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Exemplo:**

```
PlaySound(TEXT("HYPNOS_BGM\\new_connection.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
```